# Difference between Popen.poll() and Popen.wait()

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using the following command to run a shell command (creating a subprocess):

```
cmd = "ls"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

Then, I want to get its return code when it's finished. I should use `wait()` or `poll()`? It seems to me `wait()` is equal to a `poll()` enclosed in a busy wait. Something like:

```
while process.poll() == None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I read that `wait()` could generate a deadlock if `stdout/stderr` buffer is filled. `process.poll()` used like above also could generate a deadlock? If this is true,
I should use `process.comunicate()` to solve the problem? Nowadays, I only use
`process.comunicate()` when I'm interested in the subprocess `stdout/stderr`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [`subprocess.poll`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.poll), when used in a loop like that, will cause a deadlock if the `stdout` is piped into your process and you aren't reading from it. If you don't pipe `stdout` or you're consistently reading from it, neither [`poll`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.poll) nor [`wait`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.wait) will deadlock. [`subprocess.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.communicate) will solve the deadlock in the cases it would occur. However, if you just want to run a command, check its return code, and get its output, use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), which wraps all of that.

Comment: subprocess.check_output was introduced in Python 2.7. I'm using Python 2.6, so I'll need to implement the solution manually.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Obviously, this is a hack, but on systems with Python 2.6, I've just copied the 2.7 `subprocess.py` into the appropriate 2.6 directory and made a few syntax changes (no set literal notation in 2.6, if I recall) and it worked okay.